# Set not sorting properly the date of birth

Tags: java, sorting, import, set

I'm working on a problem where I have to import 3 text files: Doctor, Paitient, Visits. I have to find the top 5 oldest doctors on the list. Currently my method for this is looking like this :

```
private static void zadanie5(List<Lekarz> lekarz) {

    System.out.println("Zadanie5");
    lekarz.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Lekarz::getDataUrodzenia, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder())))
            .limit(5)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

When run the method will bring up the 5 people although they are not the oldest, the oldest which is displayed by the method is born in 1970, where as on the file there are people born in 1946.

The imported text file with the doctors look's like this:
(ID of the doctor, Surname, Name, Speciality, Date of birth, NIP number, Pesel number)

```
Id_lekarza  Nazwisko    Imie    Specjalnosc Data_urodzenia  NIP           PESEL
    23         Kadaj    Monika  laryngolog  1965-03-16    879-122-69-94 65031687654
```

Could you advise what could be the issue here and how I could fix the sorting?

Thanks!

Comment: To help us debug the problem it is in your best interest to provide us [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (a.k.a. [MCVE]). In other words your example needs to be ***minimal*** - which means it shouldn't have any parts unrelated to your problem, for instance you can skip reading from file, just provide raw data in code for *few* objects needed to show the problem. BUT at the same time your code needs to be ***complete*** - this means we should only copy-paste it to your machines and *without any modifications* be able to compile/run it and get *exactly the same problem* as described in question.

Comment: Don't be discouraged by potential amount of time it will need. Creating such example will also give **you** a chance to find cause of the problem yourself. For instance when you will remove/change some part to create [mcve], at some point your problem may also disappear. In such case it will give you a hint that source of the problem was in (probably recently) removed/changed part.

Comment: Are you comparing string or converting to date ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue you are having is with the order. When you use the method `Comparator.reverseOrder()` you will get the numbers from biggest to smallest. The year in which someone is born will be smaller for older people. An example of this is the year 2020 is more than 1952 even though those born in 1952 are older.

Try to use the code below.

```java
lekarz.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Lekarz::getDataUrodzenia, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
                .limit(5)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```